# How to extract data from quickbook on a third party server

Tags: quickbooks

I have a need to downloading data customer and account data from quickbook for one of their company , I have done a some research that with the the API built by Intuit we can extract the data and we need ConsumerKey, consumerSecret, AccessToken and AccessSecret) corresponding to target QB account .

Provided that we will have all the keys will it be possible to download the data using curl or any other extract tool.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit provides you with the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. Log in to developer.intuit.com and click on your app and you'll be shown those values.

The Access Token and Access Token Secret are provided to you by the OAuth flow. Go through the OAuth flow (http://oauth.net/, https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0020_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app) to get these values.

Comment: Thanks Keith , that really helps , I have all the four keys required to make an api call . Will it be possible to make a api call using curl and down load the data from quickbooks.

Comment: Using only curl? No. Using curl in conjunction with a library to handle the OAuth signing? Yes. Perhaps you should indicate what programming language you're using, so that someone can give some example code?

Comment: My bad I should have been precise .I was using curl in a shell script , But I can use python too for generating the auth signature.